# Store values submitted in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which is coded like this. http://localhost/test/index.html?Job=123456&Customer=11111&Number=32333

What i want to do is read this form data when the page is input, as i need to add Job and Customer to the html form i have which is using method="post" and using action="phppage.php" to post this data along with an array to phppage.php, which is then using $_GET["Job"]. I have tried various javascript functions from these pages, but just seem to be missing the values. I have confirmed the data will post by using `<input type="hidden" value="12345" name="Customer" id="customer">` hard coded and this is being brought through. What i need to do is set value for both required fields. Appreciate any help with the javascript function i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not secure to pass value in url like this, if you are using *javascript*, you have to use *encodeURIComponent* to encode your url.

and second, you can get the passed parameters from url using these codes:

```
var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(window.location);
var Parameters = decodedUrl.split("&");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me resolve my issue.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer. This will help me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing the link you have added here wont work since its in your local machine(which means it will be accessible only in your pc).
Second if your form is using post method for sending data to the page you cant get it with $_GET['somename']. you should use $_POST['somename']
since i cant see your code i would 
create the form reading this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
then create the php reading this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

also note that your url shows that your page is using get method to send data to the page

Comment: The reason i did not use $_GET is because these values are submitted to a .html page, and running php inside a html page is not possible, (so google searches say). When i run an var_dump() on the php page, it shows my array, but no values for the values. Which is why i am trying to post them through to phppage.php